# I want to get the new inserted rows from excel using C# with out using loops

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-addins

I have an excel add in . Which will get the data entered into excel to store it in database.

But I have like 15000 rows which already has data. If add 2 new rows to that how to get only those 2 rows with out looping through hole sheet.

Now I am doing like . There is one column called LocalUID. IF the cell does not have the value then I am treating as new Row. But to find the empty cell I looping through each row and checking the cell value null or not. Which is taking more time loop through hole excel.

```
 Excel.Range visibleCellRange = _xlUsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
          foreach (Excel.Range area in visibleCellRange.Areas)
            {
                foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
                {
                    int index = row.Row;
                    if (index <= 2)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (((Excel.Range)_xlUsedRange.Cells[index, 39]).Value2 == null)
                    {
                        rowNumbers.Add(index);
                    }
                    else if (((Excel.Range)_xlUsedRange.Cells[index, 39]).Value2 == null
                        && ((Excel.Range)_xlUsedRange.Cells[index, 40]).Value2 == null)
                    {
                        rowNumbers.Add(index);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But with huge data it is taking lot of time to get newly added rows.

So could any one suggest get the rows with out looping through the hole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This May or May not be an exact answer

I have Tried Interop But alas it didn't solve my purpose as I had almost same number of rows at all So i did some google and found [Epplus](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=epplus)

```
using (ExcelPackage xp = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    //set worksheet name
    ExcelWorksheet excelWorkSheet = xp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Misc.StringValueOfEnum(view));
    for (int j = 0; j < dtExport.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
      currClmnValue = dtExport.Rows[j].ItemArray[k - 1].ToString();
      excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 6, k].Value = currClmnValue;
    }
}
```

This Works Fast and also support various type of themeing

```
//Auto fit excel columns     
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[excelWorkSheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1, dtExport.Rows.Count + 5, columnsCount].Style.Border.Top.Style =
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1, dtExport.Rows.Count + 5, columnsCount].Style.Border.Bottom.Style =
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1, dtExport.Rows.Count + 5, columnsCount].Style.Border.Left.Style =
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1, dtExport.Rows.Count + 5, columnsCount].Style.Border.Right.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Hair;

var tables = excelWorkSheet.Tables.Add(excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1, dtExport.Rows.Count + 5, columnsCount], "Table");

tables.ShowFilter = false;

tables.TableStyle = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Dark10;

tables.ShowRowStripes = true;

tables.ShowColumnStripes = true;
```